# Can't select recent version of framework

Tags: visual-studio, .net-standard

When I create a new project, I can select .net Standard 4.7...

[image]

But, after the project is created, I can only go up to 2.0...

[image]

What is this witchcraft? I have tried editing the project file, but it doesn't seem to have made any difference.

How do I make Visual Studio find the more recent versions?

Comment: There's no witchcraft. There's no `.NET Standard 4.7.1`. Standard is a *specification*, not a framework or runtime. It means that this project runs on any runtime that supports the spec. The *full* framework goes up to 4.7.1. Core and Standard projects have their own numbers that go up to 2.0. Full 4.7.1 is compatible with Standard 2.0

Comment: In your case, you selected to create a .NET Standard class library. Standard versions go up to 2.0, the latest. You can reference a .NET Standard library from any Full Framework project

Comment: @MasterYoda the link you refer to has nothing to do with this question. There's no problem. There's no missing framework. The OP created a .NET Standard class library project.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The drop down says, "Target Framework" and in the past I've been able to select beyond 2.0. Also, in the project's references, I'm getting, "Package 'Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs 1.0.9' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project."

Comment: No you weren't, you were creating a *different* type of project. Check the screenshot. It's a `Class Library (.NET Standard)` project. This only goes up to 2.0, which [was released this August](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/08/14/announcing-net-standard-2-0/). What you created in the past is `Class Library (.NET Framework)`.

Comment: In the `Add New Project` dialog go to `Visual C#` > `Windows Classic Desktop` and select  `Class Library (.NET Framework)`. The template is *also* available in the `Visual C#` node, right below the `Class Library (.NET Standard)` option

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It's confusing trying to keep up with the changes.

Comment: As for [Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs/) the NuGet package page says `Please note that this package requires .Net Framework 4.5 Full Profile.`. The package isn't compatible with .NET Standard or Core yet.